# terminal stream operation, which takes map as an input in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Do we have some terminal function which takes a function as an input? I have an inner loop, which returns a response, as put in the below example. Rather than putting the response in outside list, I wanted inner loop to collect and send the response.

```
    List<A> consignments = Lists.emptyList();
    IntStream.range(0, days)
            .mapToObj(startDate::plusDays)
            .forEach(day -> IntStream.range(0, hours)
                    .forEach(hour -> consignments.add(myfunction()))
            );
```

I wanted it something like:

```
    List<A> consignments = IntStream.range(0, days)
            .mapToObj(startDate::plusDays)
            .forEach(day -> IntStream.range(0, hours)
                    .mapToObj(hour -> myFunction())
                    .collect(toList()));
```

Since forEach is a consumer, this won't work as it is, so do we have some easy way to achieve it, which I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your intention correctly, `flatMap` should work:

```
List<A> consignments = 
    IntStream.range(0, days)
             .mapToObj(startDate::plusDays)
             .flatMap(day -> IntStream.range(0, hours)
                                      .mapToObj(hour -> myFunction()))
             .collect(toList());
```